# Storing images to the iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to save images captured by the camera on the iphone to a custom directory or somewhere on the iphone rather than saving to the camera roll?

I would like to save images to the device and then have access to the at a later stage, rather than reading from the camera roll using ALAssets.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can save them to your apps' documents folder.  Here is an example:

```
// Create path
NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/ImageName.png"];

// Write image to PNG
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

To retrieve it:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

To list all files in a directory:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
for (NSString *s in fileList){
    NSLog(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering about the management of the images. how does one get the url for the stored image once it is saved to the folder?

Comment: @Helium3 I have updated my answer with samples of how to save as pngs (although there is a similar `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` method for jpgs), how to retrieve the saved image, and how to list the contents of a directory.

Comment: Thanks. What if the image has no name? Is there a way to just save the image to the device and get the url so that the url can be stored for later callbacks of the image? Or should names be dynamically created for each image that is captured by the camera?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to write

```
// imageData = NSData object
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imageCacheDirPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"anyFolderName"];
NSString *imageCachePath = [imageCacheDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];
[imageData writeToFile:imageCachePath atomically:YES];
```

And the following snippet to read the data again:

```
// Get path of image
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imageCacheDirPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"anyFolderName"];
NSString *imageCachePath = [imageCacheDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageCachePath];
```

Note that in this example the image is stored in a subfolder of your "Documents" folder and this folder is called "anyFolderName". The variable docsPath contains the Path to the "Documents" folder of your dir.

Note that this is only the code I use, its from iOS 3.0 times, there might be better ways to store an image to the Documents folder of your app.

Comment: saving 1000 images to iphone will cause any problem? like memory mangement issues?